# Can C++/CLI .NET use resource .resx files for localization?

Tags: .net, localization, c++-cli

I am trying to localize a managed C++ .NET DLL for multiple languages.  The forms are easy enough because they operate just like the other languages and create multiple .resx files.

I cannot find any examples of localizing embedded strings in managed C++, other than to use .RC string tables in the traditional C++ way.   Is there any way to use .resx resource files to facilitate use with resource editors like [Zeta](http://zetaresourceeditor.codeplex.com/), etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a separate resources file in managed C++ containing all the error messages of the application. To do that, right-click on your managed C++ project in the solution explorer and Add / New Item of type Assembly Resource File (.resx). Give it the name MyMessages.resx for example.

Add your strings there, for example a message with the name "Error".

In your code you can retrieve the string as follows, assuming that your root namespace name is "MyApp".

```
Resources::ResourceManager^ rm = gcnew Resources::ResourceManager(L"MyApp.MyMessages", this->GetType()->Assembly);

MessageBox::Show(rm->GetString(L"Error"));
```

You can later localize your error messages in French for example, by creating another Assembly Resource File with the name MyMessages.fr.resx.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can use *.resx to localize your applications:

[.NET Localization, Part 1: Resource Managers](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/09/30/manager.html)

[.NET Localization, Part 2: Creating Satellite Assemblies](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/14/local2.htm)

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't specifically address Managed C++.

Comment: @Mike This makes no difference.