# How can I get the URL file path in Resource.resx in Visual Studio 2022 for C++?

Tags: c++-cli

I want to include an image in my `Resource.resx` inside Visual Studio 2022 and then use that image. But how can I get that image URL path when I deploy my release application?

First I have created my resource file.

[image]

Then I have added my image.

[image]

What should I do next if I want to get the URL link to that image?
I assume that when I build the project so `release` and `debug` creates, then this `resource` file will be included as well?

Comment: Are you using winapi or .net or mfc?

Comment: What do you want to do with the image ?

Comment: @drescherjm I'm using regular C++.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I want to find the URL string to it. When I compile, then `Release` application builds. Then I want to see a folder called `Images` there and inside that folder, the `pinmap` should be.

Comment: What folder do you mean ? Why do you want an URL string ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust How else should I get it?

Comment: I can't help you if you don't answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398407/can-c-cli-net-use-resource-resx-files-for-localization/11400233#11400233

Comment: @YvesDaoust Let's say that I want to get the path to the `pinmap.png` file. When I deoply my application as release, then pinmap.png won't follow with my project. I assume that if I include my pinmap.ong to my Resource.resx, then I can get the URL path string to pinmap.png and use that?

Comment: The question is what you mean by *use*. I am not cutting hair, just trying to sort out your XY question.

Comment: There is no URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources, where to put them, and how to reference them in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111160/resources-where-to-put-them-and-how-to-reference-them-in-c-sharp) The same mechanism applies, just do it in C++/CLI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After importing your image into the Resource File you can then reference it from the code using the [LoadResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadresource) function.

You would load an image file this way:

```
HANDLE hImage = LoadResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MYIMAGE));
```

There is no "URL" or "Path" to the image because it is stored in the executables data section. You merely reference these resources by an identifier. The ID is also specified by the resource file.

Comment: `LoadResource` not found.

Comment: I recall having linked the necessary documentation. If there is something else wrong with your code, please provide more information.

Comment: Okey, How can I convert `hImage` to byte array?

Comment: possibly open a new question for this.

Comment: Ok. Can you change your question how to get MAKEINTRESOURCE? This is not a complete answer. Thank you.

Comment: The question is complete. MAKEINTRESOURCE is a macro defined in Windows.h again.. linked in my resource.

Comment: And where do I get `IDR_` macro?

Comment: I have also told you that. Please do your own research. That is defined as the ID by your Resource File

Comment: No. It's not defined there. There is a macro defined there, but it's a number. I cannot add a number to MAKEINTRESOURCE.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makeintresourcea